# Interactive Python console in Eclipse on remote server

Tags: python, eclipse, console, interactive

I would like to be able to use the interactive PyDev console within Eclipse. Eclipse itself however is located on a remote Linux Fedora server and is running via a Remote-Desktop Tool (NoMachine 3.5) on Win 7.

As long as I run my code in a normal console everything works fine, a click on the interactive console however reveals some problems, that seem to suggest that I get stuck in the firewall.

```
Error initializing console.
   Unexpected error connecting to console.
   Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. 
   Last msg received: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Unauthorized
Command Line used:  $HOME/.local/lib/anaconda/bin/python -u $HOME/software/eclipse/dropins/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.2.0.201312292215/pysrc/pydevconsole.py 59370 27710 59370 27710
```

This is somehow surprising, because obviously I could connect to the server via a proxy already and I'm working on it non-interactively. Any suggestions on how to get this running would be highly appreciated.